# cancel option not available while asking new question

Tags: support, asking-questions

At times while I prepare a new question, need to abandon the asking of that Question.
Surprisingly, there is no option such as 'cancel' button.
I need to go back to earlier page or click on a different link.
I know this may not be a very serious issue, still it would be better to have a cancel option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option to cancel what you have written for both questions and answers. (Don't mind what I wrote in the question and answer field :D)

> **[image]**

Discard doesn't appear instantly. It appears after there are some characters in the body and  at least 15 characters in the title. It takes a minute or few to  This time has been inconsistent for questions and answers.

> *[image]*

For answers I have tested with words but looks like it is based on time. Once I was shown the option only after writing one sentence and in some other instances, I waited till I wrote two or more sentences.

> *[image]*

This delay is due to the time taken by Stack Exchange servers to gather up related questions in suggestion list and to save what you have written. If that one option appears and even if you close your tab, you will be shown the same text you wrote. If it's blank, there's no need to save a draft and you can start a new question from scratch. I guess this will get a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) if a dev sees it as it is a minor issue. There is always Caching.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time & effort. Very nice explanation.

Answer (score 6):

That is called draft which is a [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/260388) that automatically saves your QA text before posting. There is an option called [**discard**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126299/260388) provided to manually clear saved draft.

An image for reference:

[image]

As you can see "Discard" option beside "Post your question" button. It works as cancelling only.

Comment: Thanks. But I think there is some catch. For initial some time (approx. a minute), the option doesn't show. As I was just gazing on the page, after some time, the 'Discard' link appeared. (I am using Irridium browser; LUbuntu latest LTS). You may test the repeatability on your platform. Open different browser window/tab and try it. Just post your experience here.

Comment: @Vineet It appears after there are some minimum characters to fill the requirements of the question viz 15 characters in the title and some words in the body. I tried it just now.

Comment: May we call it a bug? because a user may wish to cancel the asking  before completing this requirement!

Comment: @Vineet there is no need. Since if a user don't write anything it won't be drafted anyway.